# How to modify magento 2 checkout page login popup?

Tags: magento2, frontend, html

I'm trying to customize the checkout page and there is a small link so the user can access the account on the checkout page but I can't customize my changes don't reflect on the front end. I don't know if it's the correct file, but what I'm editing is the "authentication.html" file

Comment: Can you please explain bit more about your question or with screen shot what you want to edit or modify?

Comment: On the Checkout page there is a modal to access the account. I'm wanting to customize this modal, but when I extend it to my theme it doesn't seem to work. I think I'm editing the correct file, but the changes don't reflect on the front-end

Answer (score 0):

To customize the modal, you can look on the side of:

- httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/template/**authentication-popup.html**

Then you have to clear the cache and regenerate the static :

- rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*
- bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: unfortunately it wasn't that file. I ended up getting it, it was the authentication.html file inside Magento_checkout

Answer (score 0):

> We have shown one example here that how can we do changes in login pop
> up on checkout page. Please follow below steps to override file.

**You have to override file vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/authentication.html** in your custom theme like app/design/frontend/{{YOUR THEME NAME HERE}}/Magento_Checkout/web/template/authentication.html

> We have changed "Email Address" field label from above overidden file.
> Here is the screenshot https://prnt.sc/1q9r1so